# How to exclude core packages of Plone?

Tags: plone

I wonder where it is defined, which dependencies Plone is pulling and how to exclude parts of it?

In my case I want to disable plone.app.theming, but I can't find any line in the eggs that defines the dependency.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can depend on 'Products.CMFPlone' instead of 'Plone' in your policy package (or just install the former instead of the latter in the eggs list in buildout.cfg). That will contain a minimal set. You may then need to pull in additional packages as required.

Leaving p.a.theming in the build shouldn't cause any problems if you don't install or enable it, though. If it does, that's a bug.

Comment: thanks, that worked. but where is the magic of the dep-defines for 'Plone' exactly?

Comment: The dependencies of the Plone egg are defined in its `setup.py`. For the current in-development version of Plone it is: https://github.com/plone/Plone/blob/master/setup.py

Comment: Thanks again. In buildout's eggs-directory, the setup.py doesn't exist. Why's that so/how does buildout know which deps to pull?

Comment: Trying to answer to myself: Informations of setup.py are transformed to the EGG-INFO-directory files, correct?